# How to check if a negative amount is input

Tags: c#

I need help checking if a negative amount is input but every time I make changes I get errors. I know I need another `do/while` loop but every time I put one in and make `amount <= 0` the compiler won't read `amount`.  This is my code of the working app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double cur1 = 0.85972;
            double cur2 = 1.16316;
            double cur3 = 1.30246;
            double cur4 = 0.76777;
            double cur5 = 0.66010;
            double cur6 = 1.51409;
            double amount;
            double total;

            int input = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("1. Euro to Sterling");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Sterling to Euro");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Euro to Dollar");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Dollar to Euro");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Dollar to Sterling");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Sterling to Dollar");
            Console.WriteLine("7. Exit");


            do
            {

                if (input == 0 || input > 8)
                    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid Option please choose again  " + input + " is not allowed");

                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your selection 1-6 and 7 to quit:");
                input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                if (input == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Euro you want converted into Sterling");
                    amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = amount * cur1;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Euros in Sterling at exchange rate {1} is = {2}", amount, cur1, total);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                else if (input == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Sterling you want converted into Euro");
                    amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = amount * cur2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Sterling in Euros at exchange rate {1} is = {2}", amount, cur2, total);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                else if (input == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Euro you want converted into Dollar");
                    amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = amount * cur3;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Euros in Dollars at exchange rate {1} is = {2}", amount, cur3, total);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                else if (input == 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Dollar you want converted into Euro");
                    amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = amount * cur4;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Dollars in Euro at exchange rate {1} is = {2}", amount, cur4, total);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                else if (input == 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Dollar you want converted into Sterling");
                    amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = amount * cur5;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Dollars in Sterling at exhange rate  {1} is = {2}", amount, cur5, total);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

                else if (input == 6)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Sterling you want converted into Dollar");

amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    total = amount * cur6;

Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Sterling in Dollars at exhange rate {1} is = {2}", amount, cur6, total);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            } while (input != 7);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to reduce all this code to the bare essentials to reproduce your problem. I doubt anyone will want to read through that. Who knows, maybe that will make you find the problem.

Comment: What do you mean the compiler won't read the `amount`?

Comment: _Why_ do you need to do this. Conversions of negative values will still work. If a user enter -1 USD and gets back -1.03 AUD, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare against 0.0, not 0.

```
do
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount in Euro you want converted into Sterling");
  amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
} while (amount <= 0.0);
total = amount * cur1;
Console.WriteLine("The amount of {0} Euros in Sterling at exchange rate {1} is = {2}", amount, cur1, total);
Console.WriteLine("Press return to go back to the Menu");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Although you could abstract this check for each case into a method to clean up and reduce your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to compare double and int